# Hiring a professor to review doctoral thesis

Tags: professorship, peer-review

Where can I find a professor to review my doctoral thesis? My current professor has a turnaround of 5 to 6 weeks before getting back to me with suggested revisions. I was hoping to hire someone to give me quicker feedback and reduce the time my professor needs to review my doc.

Comment: You have a better chance convincing your advisor to increase priority of reviewing your thesis drafts than finding someone competent to hire for the task. Is there a chance that your advisor could delegate part of reviewing to a postdoc in your research group?

Comment: Where are you making your thesis (what country), what domain (computer science is not the same as astrophysics) is your thesis about?

Comment: Does your university have an official "service standard" for how quickly supervisors should review drafts provided by doctoral students?  (The last place I worked had 4 weeks.)   Either way, what problems is it likely to cause you if you just wait the 5-6 weeks for your supervisor?

Comment: While I can understand the impulse, I'd worry that your advisor might be unhappy with your hiring outside assistance. Further, even in supposedly objective subjects (hahaha...) the approval/recommendations of an outside person are by far not guaranteed to meet approval with your advisor.

Comment: You are looking for a scientific editing service, not a professor.  There are several.

Comment: ... a further comment: in my world, the back-and-forth of revision/edit/critique etc. is a big part of the educational/professionalization experience. To hire someone else to simulate your own professionalization is bad on many levels...

Answer (score 7):

Do you know the old saying that you can have something done 1) cheap, 2) fast, and 3) good - but you can only pick two of three? That applies here.

There are not many professors available for hire for something like this. If you can even find one, I would suspect that they are not very good. Good researchers are generally busy people, who would not want to commit to proof-reading some strangers' thesis. Unless, of course, you are willing to pay a large amount of money. I am not at professor level myself, but I am qualified to read a thesis and provide comments. If you wrote and asked me, I would probably say no, because of the obvious ethical problems. But if I entertain the thought for a moment, I would ask my standard rate for external consultations which, depending on who is asking, is 2-300 €/hour. If you are willing to pay something like this, then it is a matter of sending someone you know to be good an email and asking. Expect many people to say no before someone accepts.

Comment: I think you are low-balling this. The time constraint matters. With a deadline shorter than 5 to 6 weeks, standard rates won't apply.

Comment: @Roland 5 to 6 weeks is the distant future. I'm unconvinced whether next week justifies a price hike. Tomorrow, in two days, sure.

Comment: @user2768 Asking a special rate for quick work can be justified  because you have to do something stressful (work quickly). In that case 5 to 6 weeks is probably distant future. The more important justification for a special rate for work like this is that a tight deadline puts a limit on the timing of the different tasks I must do and may preclude me from doing other things. Depending on how busy you are 5 to 6 weeks is often frighteningly close. If I have to give up on other task you'd better pay me extra.

Comment: @MaartenBuis Months are regularly given for peer-review. Is every reviewer so busy that they must plan ahead to squeeze in the review just before the deadline (or during the-month-or-so after)? Or, as I suspect, do many just do things just before the deadline? Sure, some can't get something done this week. At least, not without an incentive. Many will though.

Comment: @user2768 You can't compare peer-reviewing a manuscript that usually has been (or at least should have been) polished by experienced authors with reviewing a draft of a PhD thesis. Expectation of how much you go into depth is different.

Comment: Depends entirely on the nature of the time constraints. If I were to do something like this - which I stress again for the OP I would reject on principle - I would not want to read the full thing in one go, but rather ask for a chapter at a time, two weeks to read and provide feedback, then the next etc.
But sure, feedback on a full thesis with deadline less than a month would be difficult. I would not even entertain the thought - I don't have that much free time.

Comment: @nabla I suppose it depends on whether one accepts consultancy work and how much time can be devoted to it.

Comment: @user2768 - in my opinion there is a stronger ethical argument against this than most other consultant work.

Comment: @nabla I discuss morality in my answer. What are the _obvious ethical problems_ you hint at?

Comment: @user2768 That a thesis is supposed to be written entirely by the student themselves. Incorporating paid back-door feed back, which would in all likelihood not be credited in the thesis, is borderline cheating.

Comment: @nabla I prefer to assume everyone here is honest

Comment: @user2768 Then clearly you don't do much consulting work...

Comment: @nabla I don't follow: I assume questions are asked in good faith. I assume the OP isn't cheating.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120409/discussion-between-nabla-and-user2768).

Answer (score 2):

> Where can I find a professor to review my doctoral thesis?

**In your bibliography: You need a reviewer working in your field, so surely you must cite their work.**

> I was hoping to hire someone

A professor may feel they cannot morally accept payment from a PhD student  subsisting on a stipend. Some may be swayed by independently wealthy PhD students with the means to pay their consultancy rate. (Offering an hourly rate from the outset might entice such professors; you're merely offering a business transaction.) Others may reject on the principle that wealthy students shouldn't be able to buy an advantage. Both professors may cast judgement. It's unusual to hire a professor to review your thesis.

A professor you've collaborated with may be willing to (partially) read your thesis for free. But, you cannot demand a prompt turnaround and you should expect some delay.

Your peers may be willing to review for free too, especially if you offer to return the favour. Seek those you cite, work alongside (in your department), or those you've met (at conferences or elsewhere).

Finally, you might look for professional reviewing services that are widely advertised.

Comment: "Finally, you might look for professional reviewing services that are widely advertised." and often a scam.

Comment: @Roland Many aren't: You have some decent editors out there. Many research manuscripts would benefit from their services!